# What is the approval process for an add-in to be whitelisted for the outlook mobile list?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

Sometime ago, Microsoft Add-ins by default no longer appeared in the add-in list for the outlook mobile app. It appears only a handful of whitelisted add-ins appear. However, if you side load the add-in, it will show in the list.

What are the steps to get approval to be on this whitelisted list?

Answer (score 0):

You can find most of the information you are looking for at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-mobile-addins

Regards
Sreeram